# Open URL inside a div tag

Tags: javascript, html

I have a div tag inside a table cell and and a hyperlink tag in another cell and on i want open a specific url onmouseover on hyperlink inside the div tag.the url is to  my pdf file.Please anyone tell me how can i do this thorugh Javascript or anyother method

Comment: Can you please rewrite your question to use full, logical sentences? This is pretty hard to understand.

Comment: Could you give sample code? It's hard to get what you're trying to do here.

Comment: Brother I want to open the specific URL inside a div tag on same page where the div is placed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/291813/best-way-to-embed-pdf-in-html see this link

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like this:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
    <a href="/pdfs/test1.pdf" onmouseover="previewUrl(this.href,'div1')">google</a>
</td>
<td>
    <div id="div1" style="width:400px;height:200px;border:1px solid #ddd;"></div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

<script>
    function previewUrl(url,target){
        //use timeout coz mousehover fires several times
        clearTimeout(window.ht);
        window.ht = setTimeout(function(){
            var div = document.getElementById(target);
            div.innerHTML = '<iframe style="width:100%;height:100%;" frameborder="0" src="' + url + '" />';
        },20);      
    }   
</script>
```

Comment: Brother excpet google or google mail all links are opening but why the google is not opening u know any reason ?

Comment: it is a security restriction of the browser

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want to open a new page on mouse over, then:

```
//add onmouseover to your hyperlink
<a href="#" onMouseOver="open_new_window(url);">Open Hover Window
//then js
function open_new_window(url) {
  window.open(url,"some_name","width=300,height=200,left=10,top=10");
}
```

Did you mean something like that

Comment: No I dnt this i want to open url on same page inside a the div tag not on whole page